# symfony FOSUserbundle session end after logout

Tags: php, symfony, session

I set up all the functionality for FOSUserbundle in Symfony 3.4
All are working good i.e login, logout.

But here is the problem coming when I used to logout and click back button then the previously opened page opens that should not be opened.

Basically, I need help to destroy that session when using logout.

Comment: Well, the page is in the browser's cache. It really does not open again. With some setting we can stop browser from caching pages. It is a setting in the head of a page. I dont know the exact.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can add if you have a 'header.php' file.
It will stop caching in most browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
</head>
<body>
```